# Postgresql query plan discrepancy

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I'm attempting to debug a query which is slow on production, but fast on my development machine.  My dev box has a snapshot of the prod database which is only a couple of days old, so the contents of both DBs are roughly the same.

The query is:

```
select count(*) from big_table where search_column in ('something')
```

Notes:

- `big_table` is a [snapshot materialized view](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views#Snapshot_Materialized_Views) with about 35M rows and is refreshed daily
- `search_column` has a b-tree index.
- prod is 9.1 on ubuntu
- dev is 9.0 on OS X

## Query Plan

The results of `explain analyze`:

**prod**:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1119843.20..1119843.21 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=467388.276..467388.278 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on big_table  (cost=10432.55..1118804.45 rows=415497 width=0) (actual time=116891.126..466949.331 rows=210053 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((search_column)::text = 'something'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on big_table_search_column_index  (cost=0.00..10328.68 rows=415497 width=0) (actual time=8467.901..8467.901 rows=337164 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((search_column)::text = 'something'::text)
 Total runtime: 467389.534 ms
(6 rows)
```

**dev**:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=524011.38..524011.39 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=209.852..209.852 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on big_table  (cost=5131.43..523531.22 rows=192064 width=0) (actual time=33.792..194.730 rows=209551 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((search_column)::text = 'something'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on big_table_search_column_index  (cost=0.00..5083.42 rows=192064 width=0) (actual time=27.568..27.568 rows=209551 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((search_column)::text = 'something'::text)
 Total runtime: 209.938 ms
(6 rows)
```

and the actual results of the two queries for prod and dev are 210053 and 209551 rows, respectively.

Although the structure of the two plans are the same, what could possibly explain the differences in the costs of the above, given that there are roughly the same number of rows in this table in each DB?

## Bloat

On @bma's suggestion, here are the results of the "bloat" query for prod and dev and the relevant table/index:

**prod**:

```
current_database | schemaname |            tablename            | tbloat | wastedbytes |                             iname                             | ibloat | wastedibytes 
------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------
my_db            | public     | big_table                       |    1.6 |  7965433856 | big_table_search_column_index                                 |    0.1 |            0
```

**dev**:

```
current_database | schemaname |            tablename            | tbloat | wastedbytes |                             iname                             | ibloat | wastedibytes 
------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------
my_db            | public     | big_table                       |    0.8 |           0 | big_table_search_column_index                                 |    0.1 |            0
```

Voila, there is a difference here.

I have run `vacuum analyze big_table;` but that doesn't seem to have made any significant different to the run time of the count query.

## Config

Results of `SELECT name, current_setting(name), source FROM pg_settings WHERE source NOT IN ('default', 'override');` as suggested by bma:

**prod**:

```
            name            |         current_setting          |        source        
----------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------
 application_name           | psql                             | client
 DateStyle                  | ISO, MDY                         | configuration file
 default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.english               | configuration file
 effective_cache_size       | 6GB                              | configuration file
 external_pid_file          | /var/run/postgresql/9.1-main.pid | configuration file
 listen_addresses           | *                                | configuration file
 log_line_prefix            | %t                               | configuration file
 log_timezone               | localtime                        | environment variable
 max_connections            | 100                              | configuration file
 max_stack_depth            | 2MB                              | environment variable
 port                       | 5432                             | configuration file
 shared_buffers             | 2GB                              | configuration file
 ssl                        | on                               | configuration file
 TimeZone                   | localtime                        | environment variable
 unix_socket_directory      | /var/run/postgresql              | configuration file
(15 rows)
```

**dev**:

```
            name            |     current_setting     |        source        
----------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------
 application_name           | psql                    | client
 DateStyle                  | ISO, MDY                | configuration file
 default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.english      | configuration file
 effective_cache_size       | 4GB                     | configuration file
 lc_messages                | en_US                   | configuration file
 lc_monetary                | en_US                   | configuration file
 lc_numeric                 | en_US                   | configuration file
 lc_time                    | en_US                   | configuration file
 listen_addresses           | *                       | configuration file
 log_destination            | syslog                  | configuration file
 log_directory              | ../var                  | configuration file
 log_filename               | postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log | configuration file
 log_line_prefix            | %t                      | configuration file
 log_statement              | all                     | configuration file
 log_timezone               | Australia/Hobart        | command line
 logging_collector          | on                      | configuration file
 maintenance_work_mem       | 512MB                   | configuration file
 max_connections            | 50                      | configuration file
 max_stack_depth            | 2MB                     | environment variable
 shared_buffers             | 2GB                     | configuration file
 ssl                        | off                     | configuration file
 synchronous_commit         | off                     | configuration file
 TimeZone                   | Australia/Hobart        | command line
 timezone_abbreviations     | Default                 | command line
 work_mem                   | 100MB                   | configuration file
(25 rows)
```

Comment: Did you run "ANALYZE" on the production db before testing? Also, the dev version will likely be in an optimal state: the data is all contiguous on disk, where production (assuming normal UPDATE/DELETE usage) is likely not. Also: check for bloat: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat, and show if there are any config settings different between the servers:
SELECT name, current_setting(name), source
FROM pg_settings
WHERE source NOT IN ('default', 'override');

Comment: Re ANALYZE:  there is an autovacuum process running for the DB - how do I check if that is running ANALYZE?

Comment: Re UPDATE/DELETE - see added note about the table being a materialized view - I assume this would mean that things end up fairly similar in both environment in terms of contiguity?

Comment: Re bloat, have updated question with results from query.

Comment: re config, have added that to question

Comment: Autovacuum will run depending on settings and data churn. A manual `ANALYZE` run will update the statistics on the table in prod to ensure you have accurate statistics before running your query. The dev db might be static and the statistics are already fine. Your prod table looks pretty bloated -- I suggest a couple `VACUUM big_table` runs, and that you make you autovacuum settings more aggressive on that table.

Comment: I see your updated edit about the mat view being refreshed daily: after every refresh you could manually issue `VACUUM ANALYZE big_table` to try keep that bloat down. Also, are you doing a full refresh of your mat view? If so, are you TRUNCATE-ing the table or DELETE/UPDATE-ing it? Not really related to this issue, but is your prod `random_page_cost` set to the default of 4.0?

Comment: DELETE/INSERT (rather than TRUNCATE).  Yes, `random_page_cost` is set to default 4.  I will do an `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM` and report back here any results.

Comment: If you are recreating the entire mat view on each refresh, then a TRUNCATE followed by an INSERT is much more efficient (and faster, and repacks the data on INSERT). You might now be able to do it that way for various reasons, but the TRUNCATE method is generally preferred.

Comment: Note that @bma's suggestion to TRUNCATE rather than DELETE to mat view has roughly halved the execution time of the refresh - champion!

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess (bit too long for a comment...): it might be that the query plan used to refresh the mat view is very different due to data distributions, leading to the mat view getting filled in a completely different manner.

This could ultimately result in a similar bitmap index scan plan, but with the latter conveniently visiting a select few disk pages on your devel install, as opposed to a great many in production.

If this lead makes sense to you, could you also post the query plans used to actually create/refresh the mat view? If they widely differ (cost estimates, plans, etc.), try creating a clustered index on the mat view (possibly on the search_column itself), to see if it makes any material difference. (Don't forget to analyze after doing so.)

Answer (score 1):

If most of your queries for this materialized view table are limited by `search_column` I'd suggest running `cluster big_table using big_table_search_column_index; reindex big_table;` after refreshing it.

This would take some time and would block this table while it is running, bu this would make table data on disk sorted by this search_column. So all queried limited by `search_column` value would only have to retrieve a limited number of disk blocks and probably even from limited location on disk platters. A reindex would take care of possible index bloat after `cluster`.

I think your dev computer has an SSD drive, which is very good at retrieving data from scattered locations. In production you probably have classic rotating magnetic disk or disks, which are terrible at it. Also it was recently created, so there's no bloat (holes left after deleting data). And I think this causes a several orders of magnitude slowdown.

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion - but I should note that 'search_column' is not the only column indexed, so clustering by that may speed it up, at the expense of other searches.  Is it possible to get a measure of how "clustered" a table is based on an index, so that I don't actually have to modify the production DB?

Comment: Re SSD, my machine definitely has a traditional, magnetic, hard disc.